# unable to open google api condole

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to generate api for google maps but unfortunately, I am unable to open
google api console.

Link is :- [google console link](https://console.developers.google.com/project)

I have searched on internet a lot but no help.

I am following tutorial [google map tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm)

update:-
Attached screen shot
[image]

Comment: I tried to access link in mozilla, chrome, and IE.

Comment: What do you mean you can't open it? Are unable to login to Google?

Comment: It asks for login, I enter login id and password, it is successful but nothing is getting displayed on browser.

Comment: You're accessing the projects link directly. Have you tried going through [here](https://console.developers.google.com) first?

Comment: Did it work? Were you able to access the link I gave you?

Comment: Yes, I tried this link still the issue is same.
attached screenshot screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111596/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and-mcawesomville).

Comment: This is odd. Have you tried accessing it in a different computer? Via mobile? Or maybe using a different connection?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but still no luck.

Comment: Finally issue got resolved.
I guess issue with Firefox browser.I just updated browser and I am able to see the page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally issue got resolved. I guess issue with Firefox browser.I just updated browser and I am able to see the page. Thanks